# Recursive relationship search functionality

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Hi I have a laravel project where im using a recursive model. It works fine but I would like to be able to return results where any of the childrens fields match a search query.

Here is my Data model

```
/**
* Declares the relationship between a log and its children
* @access public
* @return Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation
*/
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent', 'id');
}

/**
* Declares the relationship between a log and its parent
* @access public
* @return Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation
*/
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(self::class, 'parent', 'id');
}

/**
* Declares the relationship between a log and its meta data/ children
* @access public
* @return Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation
*/
public function metaData()
{
    return $this->hasMany(MetaData::class, 'parent', 'id');
}
```

Here is my meta data model

```
/**
* Declares the relationship between meta data and its parent
* @access public
* @return Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation
*/
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Data::class, 'parent', 'id');
}
```

So data is the top level and each peice of data can have meta data, but meta data can also include data meaning it will go down another level.

Here is what i use to list them

```
 $query = Self::select('data.id', 'data.created_at', 'data.type')
                 ->whereNull('parent');

    //If the user has declared a type, filter it by that type
    if ($type)
    {
        $query->where('type', $type);
    }

    $query->with('children.metaData');

    return $query->paginate($display);
```

This works fine but to incorporate a search feature im doing this...

```
if ($search)
    {
        $query->where(function($query) use ($search)
        {
            return $query->where('metaData.name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
                         ->orWhere('metaData.value', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%');
        });
    }
```

Which is an anonamyse function before returning the query. Im getting the error that the fields dont exist but I think even if they did, it would only work for the 2nd to top level data.

I would like it so it does a deep search of all its children, any help is appreciated

Comment: What database and version are you using?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir mysql latest, i solved this by adding a master column on the meta data table which refers to the top level entry. So i can do a query to search the meta data table and get all the master ids, and then do a normal query like above but do a whereIn for the array of master ids. Theres probably a better way to do it but its fairly clean and works good.

Comment: MySQL 8 also offers recursive common table expressions for cases like yours: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html